# Newbie : How evaluate model to increase accuracy model in classification

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

my data

[image]

how do I increase the accuracy of the model, if some of my models when run produce results like the one below
`

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
Accuracy: 0.6780893042575286
```

`
Random Forest Classifier : Accuracy: 0.6780893042575286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Look at the data. Are they in the best shape for the algorithm? Regarding NaN, Covariance and so on? Are they normalized, are the categorical ones translated well? This is a question too far-reaching for a forum.
2. Look at the problem and the different algorithm suitable for this problem. Maybe

- Logistic Regression
- SVN
- XGBoost
- ....

3. Try hyper parameter tuning with RandomisedsearvCV or GridSearchCV

This is quite high-level.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of model selection, you can use a function like the below to find a good model that suits the problem.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


def mutli_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
""" Function to determine best model archietecture """

    dfs = []
    models = [
              ('LogReg', LogisticRegression()), 
              ('RF', RandomForestClassifier()),
              ('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()),
              ('SVM', SVC()), 
              ('GNB', GaussianNB()),
              ('XGB', XGBClassifier(eval_metric="error"))
            ]

    results = []
    names = []
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted', 'roc_auc']
    target_names = ['App_Status_1', 'App_Status_2']

    for name, model in models:
            kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=90210)
            cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
            clf = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
            print(name)
            print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
            results.append(cv_results)
            names.append(name)

            this_df = pd.DataFrame(cv_results)
            this_df['model'] = name
            dfs.append(this_df)
            
    final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    return final
```

After model selection, you can do something called [Hyperparameter tuning](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/hyperparameter-tuning/) which will further increase the model's performance.

If you want to further improve the model, you implement techniques like [Data Augmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_augmentation) and also revisit the cleaning phase of your data.

If after all that, if it still doesn't improve you could try collecting more data or refocus the problem statement.